# Globally configuring caption max-widths

Tags: captions, indentation

I've got a series of tex documents that I want to make a few changes to for the sake of readability. One that I can't quite get sorted out cleanly (i.e without a massive regex) is setting a max-caption-width; as some of the captions are several lines long and end up looking the same as the body text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption) package. To globally reduce the caption width you just need to say something like

```
\usepackage[margin=10pt]{caption}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: `\usepackage[width=7cm]{caption}` would also do.